# Naive Bayes and kNN accuracy

Tags: accuracy, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour

Assume that a large number of binary features are added to a dataset with two
class labels c1 and c2, such that for each added feature f, the class conditional
probability P(f = 0|c1) = P(f = 0|c2). What effect will the addition
of such features have on the accuracy of naive Bayes and kNN respectively?

I calculated for Naive Bayes P(c1| f1=0,..,fn=0) and P(c2| f1=0,..,fn=0) obtaining then that are the same as relative frequences of both classes, but how could this affect the accuracy?